# Setting function symbols lexically

Tags: common-lisp, lexical-scope

I'm looking for a way to easily, temporarily swap functions out.
I know that I can manually set a function symbol like so:

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'abcd) #'+)
#<FUNCTION +>
CL-USER> (abcd 1 2 4)
7
```

I also know that `labels` or `flet` can temporarily set names for functions defined in place:

```
CL-USER> (labels ((abcd (&rest x) 
                    (apply #'* x)))
            (abcd 1 2 4))
8
```

Is there a way to manually, lexically set a function name? Eg.:

```
CL-USER> (some-variant-of-labels-or-let ((abcd #'*))
            (abcd 1 2 4))
8
```

Note: I tried poking into the source of labels and flet, but both are special operators. No joy.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bindings that you can modify with `symbol-function` aren't lexical bindings, so that sort of option doesn't really apply.  The only way to establish lexically bound functions is through labels and flet, so you'll have to use those.  That said, you can get kind of syntax you want pretty easily with a macro:

```
(defmacro bind-functions (binder bindings body)
  `(,binder ,(mapcar (lambda (binding)
                       (destructuring-bind (name function) binding
                         `(,name (&rest #1=#:args)
                                 (apply ,function #1#))))
                     bindings)
            ,@body))

(defmacro fflet ((&rest bindings) &body body)
  `(bind-functions flet ,bindings ,body))

(defmacro flabels ((&rest bindings) &body body)
  `(bind-functions labels ,bindings ,body))
```

Both fflet and flabels take function designators (a symbol or a function) and call apply with them and any additional arguments.  Thus you could use `#'*` or `'+`.

```
(fflet ((product #'*)
        (sum '+))
  (list (product 2 4)
        (sum 3 4)))
;=> (8 7)
```

This does mean that you're introducing the overhead of `apply`, but it's not clear what you could do to avoid it.  Since lambda expressions could refer to the bound names, we could either allow those references to be to the newly bound function, or to whatever is outside.  This is the difference between flet and labels, as well, and that's why implemented versions based on each:

```
(fflet ((double (lambda (x)
                  (format t "~&outer ~a" x)
                  (list x x))))
  (fflet ((double (lambda (x)
                    (format t "~&inner ~a" x)
                    (double x))))                           ; not recursive
    (double 2)))
; inner 2
; outer 2
;=> 2 2
```

```
(flabels ((factorial (lambda (n &optional (acc 1))
                       (if (zerop n) acc
                           (factorial (1- n) (* acc n)))))) ; recursive
  (factorial 7))
;=> 5040
```

---

### Alternatives

After mulling over this for a while, it occurred to me that in Scheme, `fflet` is the same as `let`, since Scheme is a Lisp-1.  To get the behavior of `flabels`, you have to use `letrec` in Scheme.  Searching for implementations of `letrec` for Common Lisp turns up some interesting results.

Robert Smith's [*Letrec for Common Lisp*](https://bitbucket.org/tarballs_are_good/letrec) includes this description and example:

> LETREC:LETREC is a macro which aims to imitate Scheme's letrec form.
>   It is a useful construct for functional programming in Common Lisp,
>   where you have function-producing forms which need to be functionally
>   bound to a symbol.
>
> ```
>   (defun multiplier (n)
>     (lambda (x) (* n x)))
>
>   (letrec ((double (multiplier 2))
>            (triple (multiplier 3)))
>     (double (triple 5)))
>   ;= 30
> ```

This has the same issue with apply, of course, and the notes include

> Unforunately, the macro isn't a very efficient implementation. There
>   is a level of indirection with the function calling. Essentially, a
>   LETREC with the binding
>
> ```
> (name fn)
> ```
>
> is expanded to a LABELS binding of the form
>
> ```
> (name (&rest args)
>   (apply fn args))
> ```
>
> which is somewhat abysmal.
>
> Patches are welcome for implementation-specific ways of implementing
>   the macro.

In 2005, [user rhat asked on comp.lang.lisp](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/comp.lang.lisp/HqDtDUNyWk8/C86UmkNvDB4J) about a Common Lisp equivalent to Scheme's letrec, and was pointed at labels.

Answer (score 1):

You can set synonymous name for a globally defined function with [`symbol-function`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_symb_1.htm):

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'factorial) #'!)
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION !>
CL-USER> (factorial 5)
120
```

The problem with this is that you get it permanently and globally. But you can remove the definition with [`fmakunbound`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_fmakun.htm#fmakunbound):

```
CL-USER> (fmakunbound 'factorial)
FACTORIAL
CL-USER> (factorial 5) ; now here is no such function
; Evaluation aborted on #<SYSTEM::SIMPLE-UNDEFINED-FUNCTION #x19F36199>.
CL-USER> (! 5) ; still works
120
```

I would like to propose this macro, based on said functions:

```
(defmacro with-synonyms (params &body body)
  `(prog2 (setf ,@(mapcan (lambda (x)
                            `((symbol-function ',(car x)) #',(cadr x)))
                          params))
     (progn ,@body)
     ,@(mapcar (lambda (x) `(fmakunbound ',(car x)))
               params)))
```

It works as you want:

```
CL-USER> (with-synonyms ((product *) (sum +))
           (product 2 (sum 2 3)))
10
```

Macroexpansion:

```
(PROG2 (SETF (SYMBOL-FUNCTION 'PRODUCT) #'*
             (SYMBOL-FUNCTION 'SUM)     #'+)
  (PROGN (PRODUCT 2 (SUM 2 3)))
  (FMAKUNBOUND 'PRODUCT)
  (FMAKUNBOUND 'SUM))
```

Outside of the macro body there are no such functions as `product` or `sum`.

NOTE: These synonymous functions are still defined globally (for short time, though), so this solution is not ideal.

---

P.S. Actually `(setf symbol-function)` is very-very evil thing.

```
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function 'normal-plus) #'+)
#<SYSTEM-FUNCTION +>
CL-USER> (defun magic-plus (&rest rest)
           (if (every (lambda (x) (= 2 x)) rest)
               5
               (apply 'normal-plus rest)))
MAGIC-PLUS
CL-USER> (setf (symbol-function '+) #'magic-plus)
#<FUNCTION MAGIC-PLUS (&REST REST) (DECLARE (SYSTEM::IN-DEFUN MAGIC-PLUS))
  (BLOCK MAGIC-PLUS (IF (EVERY (LAMBDA (X) (= 2 X)) REST) 5
(APPLY 'NORMAL-PLUS REST)))>
CL-USER> (+ 2 3)
5
CL-USER> (+ 5 5)
10
CL-USER> (+ 2 2)
5
```

Comment: (setf (symbol-function '+) #'magic-plus) gives me Lock on package COMMON-LISP violated when setting the symbol-function of +... under SBCL. Sounds too evil to be true. What lisp are you using?

Comment: @BnMcGn, GNU CLISP, and it works. I was playing with `(setf symbol-function)` for a while and eventually created this mess. I think it must not work, but in GNU CLISP it does. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: It might be prohibited, but I think it's more likely just undefined behavior. According to [11.1.2.1.2 Constraints on the COMMON-LISP Package for Conforming Programs](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/11_abab.htm) which includes in the list of things that have undefined consequences: "2. Defining, undefining, or binding it as a function."

Comment: So, doing this with `+` is a bad idea, but using `symbol-function` to provide a *dynamic* redefinition is fine, in general.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor, `+`-magic is included into answer just for fun ;-) My idea was to avoid use of `apply`, I think the implementation is not too bad.

Comment: Note that this is not a temporary lexical binding, which the original question asked for (at the end), but a (rather unsafe :) dynamic binding of the function name.